# Email coding : Gmail and Gmail app seems to be ignoring my CSS

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, html-email

I have an email that is working properly in any other computer or mobile display, except the Gmail app and Gmail in laptop. 2 issues :

- I added a @media code in the css in order for the images to be responsive when viewed on mobile (width:100%), but gmail app (tested both in a samsung phone and apple phone) seems to be ignoring it. So my images appear smaller, with the fixed width specified for big screens. 
  Here is the result : http://screencast.com/t/nm3jyc47K. The expected result, is to have the images filling 100% of the table (almost all the screen if we exclude the spacers), and obviously centered.
- On the Gmail laptop website, my spacers between the tables seems to be ignored, therefore inline elements are touching each other. Here is the result : http://screencast.com/t/3D7H0Fqly. The expected result is a 24px spacer in between. (PD : Don't bother about the size, I was doing some testing, the size on desktop appear properly)

Here is the HTML code of the images, 3 images and 2 spacers in between.

```
<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="m-width w-170" style="max-width:100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <a href="img-1.png" style="border:none; display:block;height:136px" width="170px" /></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!--[if mso]></td><td width="24"><![endif]-->

<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="m-width w-24" style="max-width:24px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td height="1" style="font-size:1px;line-height:1px">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<!--[if mso]></td><td width="170" valign="top"><![endif]-->

<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="m-width w-170" style="max-width:100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <a href="img-2.png" style="border:none; display:block;height:136px" width="170px" /></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!--[if mso]></td><td width="24"><![endif]-->

<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="m-width w-24" style="max-width:24px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td height="1" style="font-size:1px;line-height:1px">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!--[if mso]></td><td width="170" valign="top"><![endif]-->

<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="m-width w-170" style="max-width:100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <a href="img-3.png" style="border:none; display:block;height:136px" width="170px" /></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And now the css code, in the head part of the email :

```
<style type="text/css">
body{width:100% !important;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;margin:0;padding:0;background-color:#ffffff}
* {-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased}
.ExternalClass * {line-height:100%}
table td {border-collapse:collapse}
.wlf {width:600px}
.w-420 {width:420px}
.w-170 {width:170px}
.w-120 {width:120px}
.w-24 {width:24px}
.w-15 {width:15px}
@media only screen and (max-width:590px) {
    .full-width {width:100% !important}
    .m-width {width:100% !important;max-width:100% !important;float:none !important}
    .m-block {display:block}
    .m-none {display:none}
    .m-img-ft {width:100% !important;height:auto !important;max-width:250px !important}
    div {box-sizing:border-box !important}
}
</style>
```

And again, I have no issue whatsoever with all the other email programs. Any idea what may be wrong in order to fixed these both issues ? (Without compromising the display in the others ?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you found the reason that most HTML email developers have very little hair and a slight twitch in their left eye.  There is unfortunately no 'standard' for HTML for email across each email client, so you get a great diversity in not just what tags/styles are accepted, but also on what exactly each of those will do.

For your issue, the reason it seems to be ignoring it is because **it is** stripping your style tag out completely. ([ref](https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-gmail-and-css-part-1))  Gmail app (on desktop and mobile) pretty much strips everything out of the head and Gmail web client has [very limited 'hacky' support on stylesheets](http://freshinbox.com/blog/interactive-emails-in-gmail-using-css-attribute-selectors/).

A great resource to see what is accepted by the major email clients: [CampaignMonitor/CSS](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Keep in mind, when you fix it on Gmail, it will likely wind up breaking it on a different email client. I would recommend getting an acid testing service like Email on Acid or Litmus, etc.

You will likely need to start designing for Gmail App first and then using CSS / 'Ghost tables' or MSO conditionals to make it work for desktop.

Sample places for Fluid Responsive templates:

http://tedgoas.github.io/Cerberus/

https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-marketing/our-gift-to-you-a-free-fluid-hybrid-email-template

http://labs.actionrocket.co/the-hybrid-coding-approach-2

Comment: Ok I understand, this explains it all. So based on your answer, I managed to solve the issue of the problem n°2, by adding an inline css to my spacers : width:24px;. This allowed gmail to read them and apply them properly. The email is now displaying well everywhere, except for mobile gmail app.

But here, I don't have any clue of how to do the trick, because it comes with a media query : @media only screen and (max-width:590px). And this one I believe there is no way on earth to apply it inline.

I need the table to be :

Comment: I need the table to be :

                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                float: none !important

And the image to be :

                width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important;
                max-width: 250px !important

How do email programers would usually apply it for gmail mobile app ?

Comment: I edited my answer to include places to get Fluid Responsive templates.  This is really the only solution to get a responsive email in Gmail App that will continue to work on most desktop clients still.

Answer (score 1):

**Gmail doesn't support the `<style>` tag, so you have to inline all CSS.** All other email clients support the `<style>` tag, so if it weren't for Gmail we'd be able to write html email like a web page. It's safest to inline CSS by hand, though there are a few CSS inlining tools that can speed things up.

Regarding spacers, something like this works across email clients:

```
<!-- Clear Spacer : BEGIN -->
    <tr>
        <td height="40" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
<!-- Clear Spacer : END -->
```

**Note:** I wrote the first sample template referenced in Gortonington's answer (hello!) and can vouch that all CSS and spacers within that repo work in Gmail / Gmail app.